# Way to make Prolog syntax look like first order logic syntax?

Tags: syntax, prolog

I am looking for ways to make a Prolog program "look" more like first order logic. Things I would like to have are for example:

- -> for implication
- antecedent to the left of ->
- ^ for conjunction v for disjunction

Or is there other software that already implements this?

Thanks in advance!

/JC

***Update 20190313***
I followed the suggestions in the answers below and tried this:

```
:- op(1200, xfx, ==>).
:- op(1000, xfy, /\).
:- op(1100, xfy, \/).

term_expansion(A ==> B, B:- A).
term_expansion(A /\ B, A, B).
term_expansion(A \/ B, A; B).

man(X) /\ unmarried(X) ==> bachelor(X).

man(john).
man(peter).
unmarried(john).

main:-bachelor(X), writeln(X), nl, fail.
```

But i get the following error:

```
ERROR: bachelor/1: Undefined procedure: (/\)/2
   Exception: (5) man(_1740)/\unmarried(_1740) ?
```

Only using the op/3 and term_expansion/3 for ==> however works as expected. Not sure why this is so...

Comment: Try building a metainterpreter for it.

Comment: @DanielLyons thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer refers to your updated question ("Update 20190313").

Be careful when defining operators:

1. Don't redefine standard operators, changing their specifier/precedence.

   This can introduce errors in existing code which are *very* hard to find.
2. Weigh benefits and costs upfront.

   Aim at readability, shorter code, and fewer parentheses.

   Keep in mind that using too many custom Prolog operators can also obfuscate code and confuse the reader.
3. Think twice before using standard operators in different domains.

   Let's take the predefined `(\/)/2` as an example.

   - It is an evaluable functor in arithmetic expressions—used with `(is)/2`, `(=:=)/2`, `(<)/2`, etc.
   - clpfd uses it for representing set unions like `1..3 \/ 5..7`—fine!
   - However, using it for denoting list concatenation is questionable.

---

Let's get to your actual question!

Consider these queries decomposing some terms using `(=..)/2` ("univ"):

```
?- term_expansion(A /\ B, A, B) =.. Xs.
Xs = [term_expansion, A/\B, A, B].

?- term_expansion(A \/ B, A; B) =.. Xs.
Xs = [term_expansion, A\/B, (A;B)].
```

So it's `term_expansion/2` for `(\/)/2`, but `term_expansion/3` for `(/\)/2`!

The bottom line: **`(',')/2` terms as arguments need parentheses.**

```
?- term_expansion(A /\ B, (A,B)) =.. Xs.
Xs = [term_expansion, A/\B, (A,B)].
```

Comment: `(',')/2` terms

Comment: ad 2: What is a different domain? Think of `(+)/2` for `(is)/2` and `(#=)/2`

Comment: @false. different domain: integer bitwise-or vs disjunction. is domain the right word?

Comment: Kind-of.  And then, consider the rôle of `(-)/2` as pair and as arithmetic expressions.

Comment: @false. I see. I redid the ranking and added some wording... hoping it's clearer now.

Comment: Some more details about this here [link](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/term-expansion-2-to-make-prolog-syntax-look-more-like-classical-fol/389)

Answer (score 4):

Use term_expansion/2 that is macro of Prolog on SWI-Prolog:

```
% calc.pl
:- op(1200,xfx,--).
term_expansion(A--B,B:-A).

integer(I)
--%----------------------- (E-Int)
I => I.

E1=>I1, E2=>I2, I is I1+I2
--%----------------------- (E-Add)
E1+E2 => I.

:- 1+2+3=>6.
:- 1+2+3=>I,writeln(I).
:- halt.
```

and run

```
$ swipl calc.pl
6
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; it looks interesting. I don't fully understand the example, for example what is the meaning of =>. Is term_expansion(A--B,B:-A) a way to tell Prolog to replace every instance of A--B with B:-A? Could you point me to some examples online?

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few Unicode characters that can help you:

```
¬ 

→ ⇒

← ⇐

∨ ∧

∀ ∃
```

I leave defining suitable precedences as a challenge, using `op/3`.

Once you have these definitions, you can write first-order sentences with them. You can then convert these sentences to Prolog, or interpret them *with* Prolog.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: i tried your suggestions (see the update to my original question). I do not get it to work, however. Maybe you know what's wrong. Thanks!